# Answering to eviction case with no "final judgement"

Tags: united-states, florida, eviction

I have a friend who has an eviction on his record. I'm trying to help him get it removed since when I looked up the case, there is no "final judgement" or "writ of possession" and it still shows up as open.

My friend has since moved on from the apartment and the landlord has had possession for some time now. So I doubt he has any interest in pursuing the issue any further.

Would filing an answer to the eviction stating that he turned in the apartment within the time frame requested, and that he didn't pay the rent for several months due to the landlord's failure to maintain the property due to a leak from the apartment above cause the court to set a "final hearing" date?

My thinking is, if we get the court to set a "final hearing" date. I doubt the landlord will show up. If we win, then the eviction never happened.